# Javascript : window.postMessage not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postmessage

Hope you are doing good.
I am stuck with **window.postMessage** method.

I am sending one page data to another page using **window.postMessage**

when I print data that is being sent from one page on the another page, at that time I get below value

**{"action":"match","value" :null}**

How can I solve it ?

Below is my code.

First File from which data is being sent

```js
var win = window.open('/newPage, '_blank');
        setTimeout(() => {
            
            win.postMessage("Some Data ", "*")
        }, 1200);
```

Second file in which data is being Fetched.

```js
componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("reset",this.setMessage)
        window.addEventListener("message", this.setMessage, false)
    }

    setMessage = (evt) => {
        
        this.setState({
            dataValue: evt.data
        })
    }
```

when I print **evt.data** in the second file then sometimes I get value as

{"action":"match","value":null}

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to send probably cannot be serialized, or does not have enumerable properties.

Comment: okay.. then how can I solve this issue? actually it does not happen every time. It happens randomly.